# Django - why are my paths going through anaconda?

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When i put a return render code in my views.py I get an error when i go to `http://localhost:8000/`

**Also why are my paths going through anaconda?**

I don't get this error when I do this

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request): 
return HttpResponse("Yorleì's")
```

I've included my Template settings

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render (request, 'homepage/home.html')
```

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
homepage/home.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 3.1.2
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    homepage/home.html
Exception Location: /Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  /Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/yorleydis/yorleico',
 '/Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python38.zip',
 '/Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8',
 '/Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/Users/yorleydis/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aeosa']
Server time:    Sun, 29 Nov 2020 12:53:02 -0500
```

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Exactly where is your template located, can you show (relevant parts) of the filetree?

Comment: I had to add the folder/app i created,  to the apps section in my settings! thank you for the prompt response! :D

Comment: **@WillemVanOnsem** my template is in my hard drive - under my user and then i started a new project on my desktop. what should i show you? , idk.. 
 I'm learning as i go here